# No longer than 2 hours condition in BPMN 2.0 diagram

Tags: business-process, bpmn

I'm using Enterprise Architect and the following exercise is for educational purposes.

My exercise is to draw a BPMN 2.0 business process diagram(s) about user querying data from a bus station website. The exercise states that all restrictions should be described before the actual diagram (no idea what that means). However, the actual exercise: the user should be able find routes between two cities with passenger and cargo buses - direct and with maximum two deviations from the main route (those deviations ***should be no longer than 2 hours***).

[image]

I'm not quite sure what I did is correct, so I would like someone to correct me if I'm wrong and the main issue is how do I handle the "no longer than 2 hours" condition for the deviations from the main route.

Comment: This diagram makes no sense to me. I don't get why both "direct" and "with deviations" would put you in the same state, or even exist on the diagram. It seems like those are one of the search criteria that is being submitted before the form is validated. I would think that "no longer than 2 hours" is also a search criteria. It boils down to you're modeling a simple form submission and not a business process, which may not be a good fit for the tools you are using.